# How to get Row value on button Click

Tags: asp.net, button, repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
  OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDatabound">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%#Eval("Priority") %>
        </td>
        <td>
        <%#Eval("ProjectName") %>
        </td>                 
        <td>
          <%#Eval("DisplayName") %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"
            NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("EmailID" , "mailto:{0}") %>'
            Text='<%# Eval("EmailID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%#Eval("ProjectID") %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:Button ID="btnCompleteProject" runat="server" Text="Close Project"
            OnCommand="CloseProject"  CommandName="Close"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProjectID") %>' />
```

How do I get the ProjectID of the Row in which I click the close Project Button(btnCompleteProject) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an [ItemCommand event](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFsQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx&ei=K_7yT9ipIYjH0QHdwuHyCQ&usg=AFQjCNFLG3qIXZc5ywLySaCQFlAIENHxfw&sig2=z795QAVFg7-pGTT7BjKwhg) to the repeater control and add a cole something like this:

```
public void Repeater1_ItemCommand(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) 
{
    // check if the command name is close (if it's the button)
    if (e.CommandName == "Close") {
       // get CommandArgument you have seeted on the button
       int projectd = (int)e.CommandArgument;

       // your code here...

    }
}
```

And add the repeater tag, you event:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" 
   runat="server" 
   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
   OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDatabound" 
   OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
...
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: will this give me the ProjectID ? because projectId is a different column alltogether <td>
          <%#Eval("ProjectID") %>
        </td>

Comment: @user1373852 - yes, you will get the ProjectID in the `CommandArgument` (although it will be in string form) because you have `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProjectId")%>'` as an attribute on the button

Comment: @Pradit, yes like freefaller said. In Databoudn controls (repeater, datalist, gridview) you can add linkButton or Buttons, set the CommandName/CommandArgument and get these values in Command event to execute some custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnClick="btnCompleteProject_Click"` to the button markup, and add a handler:

```
protected void btnCompleteProject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var argValue = (int)((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
}
```

You could also listen to Repeater.ItemCommand, which should also catch the button click.

Comment: But how do I fetch the value of ProjectID column ?  It does not have a control or anything linked with it :s

Comment: @user1373852 You're putting ProjectID into the Button's CommandArgument, grab it from there...

Answer (score 0):

Brian Mains's answer is correct, in the markup you are setting the ProjectID column's value in the buttons command argument. so in the button click with this code

```
protected void btnCompleteProject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   var argValue = (int)((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
 }
```

you will get the ProjectID